# strings with space between them

Tags: c, string, compiler-construction

I'm trying to write a Lexical Analyzer for C tokens by constructing DFAs for each of tokens and simulating them in C. Currently I'm trying to identify a string literal. By the definition, string literals are the characters that are enclosed between `"` .Consider the following program :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *a = "Hello "


    "World";
    printf("%s",a);
}
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```

So now I am confused whether i should consider `Hello` and `World` as seperate tokens or `Hello World` combined as a single token? Thank you ! :)

Comment: The compiler ignore if there is more then one space

Comment: any two string literals will be concated in compile time if there are only white chars between them.

Comment: @Michi , does the C compiler consider them as multiple tokens or single?, I assume the preprocessor strips all the whitespace before tokenizing ?

Comment: `"Hello"` and `"World"` are two separate *tokens*.  That's a lexical analysis consideration.  When they appear adjacent to one another, they represent two parts of a single string literal.  That's a semantic consideration -- i.e. what that combination of tokens means in C source code.

Comment: What does your language spec say?

Comment: @JohnBollinger , oh so the lexical analyzer just sends the token down the phases of the compiler seperately and the semantic analyzer concatenates them?

Comment: @PruthviRaj, yes, that would be a conventional compiler architecture.

Comment: Yes, i was thinking somewhere else :). I thought he neet to know what happens with all white spaces.

Comment: @JohnBollinger , I see , Thanks, could you please post it as an answer so that I can accept it :)

Comment: @Michi , No, I know what happens with the whitespace, but then just wanted to know how classic C lexical analyzer would consider those string literals

Comment: You're asking about an implementation detail. The C specification requires that `"Hello" "World"` be concatenated into a single string literal. It doesn't tell you how to implement that requirement. So you can do whatever you want.

Comment: @user3386109 , ah I see, i've seen source of classic implementation of C on github, it seems to consider them as seperate tokens , so I guess that's how they were implemented?

Comment: I'll take your word for it, I'm not familiar with the github project that you refer to. It is certainly reasonable to treat them as separate tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comments I wrote

> "Hello" and "World" are two separate tokens. That's a lexical analysis consideration.  When they appear as consecutive tokens, they represent two parts of a single string literal. That's a semantic consideration -- i.e. what that combination of tokens means in C source code.

That describes a view of the question in terms of conventional, generic compiler construction.  For example, the distinction is between what might be represented in a `lex` scanner definition and what would be handled in a `yacc` parser description (to put it in terms of the traditional tools).

In practice, C defines a larger and more detailed set of "translation phases" for building an executable program from C sources (C99 5.1.1.2).  In C's particular model of the process, the `"Hello"` and `"World"` are separate *preprocessing tokens*, identified in translation phase 3.  These are concatenated into a single token at translation phase 6.  All (remaining) preprocessing tokens are converted to straight-up *token*s at transalation phase 7.  The resulting tokens are then the input to the semantic analysis (also part of phase 7).

C does not require implementations to actually implement translation (compilation) according to the given model, with all its separate phases, and many do not.  C just requires that the end result be *as if* the implementation behaved according to the model.  In that sense, your question can only be answered "it depends".  As far as a non C-specific conceptualization of the inferred question "what is a token", however, I will maintain that my original, short, description provides a useful mental model.

Comment: Thank you, It'd be helpful if you can cite me a link to those `transition phases` you are referring to so I can read upon :)

Comment: @PruthviRaj, I gave you a citation to the appropriate section of the (C99) standard.  You can find information about where to get the referenced document here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents